# Read/parse XLSX file, keeping fonts

Tags: linux, excel, perl

Is there a Perl module/program/method that can, from within Linux, read the text in an XLSX file that has font formatting?

It doesn't have to be Perl, but Perl is what I'm most familiar with, so Perl would be best.

For example, a single cell might say:

> *King Kong* is my favorite book.  I like it more than *1984*.

I read a bunch of posts and downloaded a bunch of perl modules and samples, but they are all simply extracting the text.  I'd really like to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read XLSX files you'll need to get to grips with `Win32::OLE` - it's a bit of a painful process, but it's not impossible.

Microsoft provides some sample code: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214797

But at a basic level for reading from a spreadsheet you'll need something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

my $excelfile = 'Book1.xlsx';

my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
my $Book  = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($excelfile);
my $Sheet = $Book->Worksheets("Sheet1");

print $Sheet->Range("a2")->{Value}, "\n";

my $cell = $Sheet->Range("a2");

foreach my $key ( keys %$cell ) {
    print "$key, ", $cell->{$key} ? $cell->{$key} : 0, "\n";
}
```

I think you'll be needing:

```
Font, Win32::OLE=HASH(0x1b2720c)
```

E.g:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %{$cell->{Font}} ) {
    print "$key, ", $cell->{Font}->{$key} ? $cell->{Font}->{$key} : 0, "\n";
}
```

This will tell you if the whole cell is italic. (Or bold, or whatever). I haven't yet dug out the element that'll tell you if substrings are formatted.

Edit: Nope, I can't see any 'sub-cell' formatting, but clearly it *can* be done.

With the additional detail - it's Linux:

`Win32::OLE` isn't an options - that's the easy way, as it 'automates' Excel (same mechanism as VB uses).

However, one of the advantages of XLSX is that it's actually an XML based archive format.

So something like this might work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip;
use XML::Twig;

my $archive = Archive::Zip -> new ();

$archive -> read ( 'Book1.xlsx' );

my $thing = $archive -> memberNamed('xl/sharedStrings.xml');
print $thing -> contents();

my $parser = XML::Twig -> new( pretty_print => 'indented' ) -> parse ( $thing -> contents() );

$parser -> print;
```

Now, that's a bit rough, because it'll just dump the XML. I *think* the formatting has each 'cell' as `<si>` elements.

So you can do:

```
foreach my $element ( $parser -> root -> children('si') ) {
    print $element -> text,"\n";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, somebody edited my post to remove the fact that I'm running on Linux, and it looks like the Win32::OLE module will not run on Linux.

Comment: Ugh. Considerably more annoying then. You can _probably_ unzip the xlsx (it'z a zip file format) and parse the contents.

Comment: Ok, my quick test suggests that you can. Might need to fiddle a bit more to parse, given tags are a subset (but one that doesn't necessarily follow the same nesting rules)